# Is qmail needed if there are not email accounts?

Tags: linux, email-server, email

I've inherited a server with some pages running. The person who worked on it has gone and there is no way to contact him. Recently I had some problems with the qmail service on this server (created a big number of files) without any obvious cause. In a metting somebody recommended to disable qmail if nobody was using it. I checked qmail and nobody was using it, so I'm thinking in disable it definitively.

But before doing this, I would like to ask you because this is a production system and I wouldn't like to broke anything. This server is used only as HTTP server (there are 20 websites), no mail, no FTP, no user shells, nothing. Some websites sends email (contact forms, sign up...) but I have disabled qmail some minuts and force a couple of websites to send and email and it worked.. So, the question is: is qmail needed for something I'm not seeing?

Comment: `qmail` hasn't been updated in 13 years; **nobody** should be running it anymore.

Comment: That's what I think..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way we can answer this for sure, but on most Linux systems some type of SMTP or sendmail like interface is expected to be able to send out mail, but usually this can be something much easier than qmail like `nullmailer` or similar minimal relay-only MTAs.

Answer (score 3):

I would take a careful look at qmail's logs over the past week or month to see whether anything is using it to process mail.  It's possible that alerts, logwatch, cron output, etc., rely on having mail available.